# How to install 64-bit libraries on 32-bit system?

Tags: 64-bit, development, 32-bit, gcc, libraries

I need to cross-compile for 64-bit architecture on a 32-bit platform (using gcc-multilib and -m64 flag).

For this I need to install 64-bit versions of the dependent libraries.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You will have to manually cross compile the libraries and store them in a non standard location ( so they don't overwrite the 32 bit ones ).

It would probably be easier to just install a 64 bit system and build it natively, or make a debian package and upload it to your PPA on launchpad and let it worry about building it on each of the architectures.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment for more information on packaging and other development issues.